# C Strings - Saving after certain characters

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
//Example 1
char * p = "/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4";
// Need to convert to....
char * p = "dir4";

//Example 2
char * p = "/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5";
// Need to convert to....
char * p = "dir5";
```

I have a character pointer p, that can change. How can I save the ending of each of those strings to a separate char pointer.

Would I loop over the string and count all the '/', then save the location of the final one? And use that to start the new string?

Comment: use `strtok()` until you get the last token.

Comment: `p = strrchr(p, '/')+1;`

Comment: @Haris: in this case, the use of `strtok` would alter a string literal, thereby yielding undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr), which scans a string from the end towards its begin until it finds a certain character:

```
int main() {

    char * p = "/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5";

    char *lastDir = strrchr(p,'/');
    if (lastDir)
        p = lastDir + 1;


    printf("p: %s\n", p);
}
```